# Implementing the Schur decomposition of a matrix

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, matrices, linear-algebra, numerical-algorithms

I'm trying do implement the [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) of a matrix, but I can't find any good articles for the theory. Could someone share one?

Answer (score -1):

It's italian but it's very clear... Read this:

[Shur decomposition](http://www.dma.unifi.it/~modica/2013-14/metodi/Cayley-Hamilton.pdf)

Proposition 6.13

Comment: Can you give a short summary and a robust link?

Comment: for an example exercise look this http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~franklan/Math416_SchurDecomposition.pdf and for theory look that: http://people.inf.ethz.ch/arbenz/ewp/Lnotes/chapter2.pdf